# what does it mean, when a girl tells a guy, "sounds like a catch"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, some-any

After you mentioned the good qualities of another female, and desire to have a female like such.

Answer (score 13):

The word 'catch' is used figuratively. It implicitly compares the person to a (good) fish that one has caught. A related use: *He | she is 'a keeper'*, that is, not a fish that one would toss back into the water. A fish worth keeping.

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/keeper?show=0&t=1419169461

When words are used figuratively, over time the underlying meaning is often forgotten, so that a person who uses these words might not be aware of the basis for the figurative meaning.

Comment: Indeed, dating terms are full of fishing / hunting metaphors, such as [_fox_](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Fox) to mean "attractive person" and websites named [Plenty of Fish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PlentyofFish).

Answer (score 11):

She is just saying that, from your description, the girl sounds like **a perfect find**, for dating or marrying.

> catch - (noun) one worth catching especially as a spouse. [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/catch)

Comment: this will do, I appreciate you taking you'r time to respond.

Comment: Or for other stuff, depending on the context.  (And there is, of course, always the danger that it's said sarcastically.)